# Do I need to put AngularJS in the <head> if I want to hide {{ xxx }} from showing on my page?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="top"
     ng-hide="app.stateService.displayModal">
   <div>{{ app.userService.data.name }}</div>
</div>

// Body HTML here.  No images are loaded. Just Divs

<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

Now the page briefly shows {{ app.userService.data.name }}.

If I want this to not show then do I have to have AngularJS in the head of my document? The reason I placed AngularJS at the end was because I wanted to have the page appear as quickly as possible.

Can someone advise me about this and also tell me how I can make the {{ xxx }} hidden when the page first loads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ng-cloak` to hide any elements until it get compiled.

```
<div id="top" ng-cloak
     ng-hide="app.stateService.displayModal">
   <div>{{ app.userService.data.name }}</div>
</div>
```

The CSS rules to hide the elements with `ng-cloak` will be added automatically by `angular.js`.

If that isn't fast enough you could add the css rules yourself at the head:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Or using the [angular-csp.css](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/blob/master/angular-csp.css) file.

Also see: [ngCloak documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways -

1. ng-bind

OR

1. ng-cloak

   {{ app.userService.data.name }}

Either way, you {{}} won't show up. no need to put angular.js inside head.

Answer (score 0):

This is the role of the `ng-cloak` directive used as a css class.

Check doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

You better use `ng-bind`

```
<span ng-bind="app.userService.data.name"></span>
```

instead of {{app.userService.data.name}}.

This will avoid that flickering.